# How to implement REST service validation with Spring Boot?

Tags: validation, spring-boot

Assuming I have the following DTO:

```
public class UserDTO {

    public Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    public String name;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    public String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
    public String phone;

}
```

And that I send the following json:

```
{
    "name": "John Lennon",
    "email": "jonnlennon"
}
```

I would like to return an error 422 with the following body:

```
[{
    "email": "it's not a valid mail"
}, {
    "phone": "required field"
}]
```

How do I implement a generic @ControllerAdvice to handle when validation errors occur? For each validation error I would get the corresponding message in a properties file.

Comment: [just googled](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use rest controller advice to handle validation error globally.
2. Make sure in rest controller put a notation @Validation for request body in method.

   @RestControllerAdvice
   public class CustomExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
       @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
       @ResponseBody
       public ErrorResponse processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
           BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
           FieldError error = result.getFieldError();
           return error.getDefaultMessage();
       }

Answer (score 0):

I created a class  to represent my error:

```
public class ErrorDetails {

    private String property;
    private String message;

    public ErrorDetails(String property, String message) {
        super();
        this.property = property;
        this.message = message;
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

And configured my **@ControllerAdvice** as below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    //others handlers

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception){

        List<ErrorDetails> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        if (exception.getBindingResult().hasErrors()) {
            exception.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> {
                errors.add(new ErrorDetails(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
            });
        }

        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(errors);
    }
}
```